# How do I set the value of a model object's property after using `get_field()`?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making a terminal command for my Django app:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
from django.apps import apps


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--app",
            dest="app",
            required=True,
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            "--model",
            dest="model",
            required=True,
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            "--col",
            dest="col",
            required=True,
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        app_label = options.get('app')
        model_name = options.get('model')
        column_name = options.get('col')

        try:
            model = apps.get_model(app_label=app_label, model_name=model_name)
        except LookupError as e:
            msg = 'The model "%s" under the app "%s" does not exist!' \
                  % (model_name, app_label)
            raise CommandError(msg)
        try:
            column = model._meta.get_field(column_name)
        except FieldDoesNotExist as e:
            msg = 'The column "%s" does not match!' % column_name
            raise CommandError(msg)
        else:
            print(column, type(column))
            # Do stuff here with the column, model.
```

Right now, `column` is `<django.db.models.fields.IntegerField: column_name>`. I want this instance of `model` to have `column_name` set to `100`. How can I set and save this instance in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to retrieve an instance of the model first based on the filter or the ID, e.g.

```
model_instance = model.objects.get(pk=1)
```

You obviously need to first decide on which instance you want to update.

Then you can do the below on the instance

```
setattr(model_instance, 'column_name', 100)
```

This will set the value of 100 to the property name 'column_name' to the model instance.

You can then run `model_instance.save()` which will save the value to the DB if you need it to.

If creating a new instance of model you can do either:

```
model_instance = model(column_name=100)
```

or

```
model_instance = model()
setattr(model_instance, column_name, 100)
```

Followed by

```
model_instance.save()
```

Comment: Try adding explanations to your answers. Just as Questions needs to be clear, so do answers.

Comment: Ah, in my case, this is for a new object -- one that does not already exist in the model. Sorry for being unclear. Is it possible to select a new object's property via string and set it?

Comment: That should be as easy as model_instance = model(column_name=100) then model_instance.save()